# Why doesn't this Ruby binary search code work?

Tags: ruby, recursion, binary-search

I have code like this

```
def search(begins, ends)
  puts "Searching for  #{begins}- #{ends}"
  temp = ((begins + ends) / 2).to_i
  if is_valid? temp
    if (ends - begins).abs < 3 # the result is between a and 2 digits than b
      return temp # recursion ends
    else
      search(begins, temp)
    end
  else
    search(temp, ends)
  end
end
```

There is a range of numbers between 0 and 10000000 that pass is_valid function. I want to find first and last element that pass this function using this code but it doesn't work it isn't even close.It go in endless loop and here are few lines of output

```
Searching for  0- 14981245
Searching for  0- 7490622
Searching for  3745311- 7490622
Searching for  3745311- 5617966 # good result
Searching for  3745311- 4681638
Searching for  3745311- 4213474
Searching for  3745311- 3979392
Searching for  3745311- 3862351
Searching for  3745311- 3803831
Searching for  3745311- 3774571
Searching for  3759941- 3774571
Searching for  3759941- 3767256
Searching for  3759941- 3763598
Searching for  3759941- 3761769
Searching for  3759941- 3760855
Searching for  3760398- 3760855
Searching for  3760626- 3760855
```

Comment: I really do not understand your code. If you explained the algorithm you are trying to implement or clarified your variable names (perhaps by using nouns) then I would much better be able to help.

Comment: I want to find same range which is within other range. I know that the beginning is between for eg  0 and 1000(with this params I call first time function begins mean when range start ends when is ends). Than I want to find  the middle number in this range (1000+0/)2 and check if this number pass valid. If yes than it means that my first number of my range number is in 0 and 500(on the left site od divided range). If no than it must be in 500 and 1000(the right site of the divided range). And I want to scan and divide this until I got the first number which pass my valid function.

Comment: And i want function to return this number temp(the first number of the range that I am searching for ). Sorry for not explaining this earlier

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code you've written: Nothing in it would cause `ends` to be anywhere near 3745311 at the point you claim. 3745311 + 7490622 is 11235933, which divided by 2 gives us 5617966 just like you're seeing. 5617966 - 3745311 is much greater than 3, so it then calculates 3745311 + 5617966, which is 4681638 — again, just as you're seeing.

I think maybe you wanted to use `ends / 2` rather than `(begins + ends) / 2`. That would cause it to be 3745311 at the point you're expecting.

Comment: if i do as U said i get stuck on this Searching for  3745311- 7490622
Searching for  3745311- 7490622

Comment: Sorry my mistake i want to find a middle of a line with start in a and ends in b so the result is correct.